# What is the equivalent of this JavaScript code in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have this JavaScript file that I need to write in C#. I've done many but stuck on it. 
Could some body help me with this?

```
var biginteger=new bigint(convert);
var mod = bigint_mod(biginteger, new bigint(97));
        var y = bigint_number(mod);
```

I am unable to interpret these JavaScript functions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx  took less than a minute to search for btw...

Comment: i can understand it, it is not worth question, but if some body can help me to interprete it, that would of great avail to write a c3 class, please

Comment: read the info at the link, ffs!! Noone is going to create a C# class for you! I would downvote but alas I'm out of votes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Numerics;       

BigInteger dividend= new BigInteger(1222222);
BigInteger mod;
BigInteger.DivRem(dividend, new BigInteger(97), out mod);
//mod will have the result
```

Or

```
BigInteger dividend = BigInteger.Parse("3243434343434434");
BigInteger divisor = BigInteger.Parse("97");
BigInteger mod;
BigInteger.DivRem(dividend,divisor, out mod);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a reference to the assembly `System.Numerics.dll` which is part of the [`BCL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) since 2010 (.NET 4.0 and later).

The use something like:

```
using System.Numerics

...

      var bigInteger = (BigInteger)convert;  // or BigInteger.Parse(convert); not sure what type convert is
      var y = bigInteger % 97;
```

Surely, the `BigInteger` struct [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_modulus.aspx) the `%` operator. And the literal `97` will be implicitly converted to a `BigInteger`.

If you don't need a new variable, you can also say: `bigInteger %= 97;`.